# C# Chart how to force labels to be on the bottom of the area and not of the axis

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart, axis-labels

My area scale is not auto, I set by myself the minimum, maximum and crossing values.
I have a chart with negative values, so my AxisY is not on the bottom of his area but in the center (or near).
Labels aren't really readable in this case (overlap by shapes).
Do you know how to force Y labels to be on the bottom of his area?

I tried to set BarLabelStyle and LabelStyle at Bottom in the series, but it didn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of a couple things. Either:

A. ASP.NET charts allow you to use more than just bottom alignment. What about one of the other ones, like [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489245.aspx) says.

B. Alter your scale so that it isn't an issue where the box shows up. You can also add fill colors so the grid lines and wayward data points don't interfere too much.

C. You could create a legend and dock it somewhere outside the chart just to label / name it.

D. Just throw a literal right above the chart as a chart name.

E. Probably your best option, though, is that it's possible to create another chart area that's completely blank with no grid lines and no data. You could make it just for the purpose of putting your label down there and set it right below or right above the chart area you're trying to label.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, the E proposition should works for me, i'll try it asap

Comment: No problem! There aren't many good resources for charts and I've had to use a lot in the past couple of months. E is what I would do in your situation. Good luck!

Comment: I didn't used E finally, because it's a bit ugly.
I show my labels only in my main chartarea